# Chrome jQuery Image Replacement is Slow

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I need a slider that changes the current image being shown.  I first tried implementing this via a src replacement:

```
$("#img").attr("src", new_src);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DJPDQ/1

This is very choppy in Chrome (but fine in all other browsers).  I could sort-of understand it being choppy the first time the image loads, but, this choppy behavior persists even after having loaded all the images.  Inspecting network activity, I see repeated GETs, but they are all cached.  Just to rule out this as a possibility, I rewrote an alternative implementation that preloads all the images, and hides all but the current image:

http://jsfiddle.net/DJPDQ/3

But this is still choppy in Chrome (and still fine in other browsers), which makes me think it has something to do with rendering/layout.

Anyone know what Chrome is doing differently, and how I might address the problem?

Comment: Have you seen the size of those images?

Comment: Yes.  I am working with large images.  But the degradation exists even after the images are cached, or, in the second implementation, loaded into the DOM.  Firefox handles them fine (even IE).  What is Chrome doing differently, and how can I handle that gracefully?

Comment: This is a hack, but it seems to work once the images are preloaded: http://jsfiddle.net/DJPDQ/4/ It does seem to have something to do with the way chrome is rendering the images. All i did was apply a small zoom to the image.

Comment: See if using z-index is smoother for you: http://jsfiddle.net/DJPDQ/5/

Comment: No better with z-index or opacity/positioning off screen either.